# inkscape, gimp user interface unreadable in Debian bullseye

Tags: debian, gimp, inkscape

Since a couple of days or updates in debian the user interface of **gimp** and **inkscape** displays only hexadecimal code (boxes with numbers) and is so unusable. 
Didn't find anything that helped like "fc-cache -f -v" and I could not find anything useful about it on the internet.
Screenshot under http://www.ulliroyal.de/inkscape-unreadable.jpg
or here[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPk5c.png)

Comment: Looking at the `/usr/share/gimp/2.0/themes/*/gtkrc` files, Gimp uses by default "Sans 11" for the interface. AFAIK there is no real "Sans" font, it is just a synonym to your system "Sans Serif" (Deja Vu, Liberation, Noto..). You can possibly check what it is and if the font exists with `fc-match "Sans"`. You can also make your own theme with a specific font...

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I checked the gtkrc file but the lines containing "Sans" were commented out with "#" so the font used must come from somewhere else for inkscape and gimp. There must be a "global" problem/solution

Comment: They are commented because they are the default... But yes the problem is likely global, and I would first wonder what the "Sans" font is aliased to and if this alias font still exists.

Comment: Yes, it must be something. A few days ago it worked and i did not mess around with the font, and i was unable to find proper keywords for a google search.

Answer (score 0):

In the file ~/.gtkrc-2.0 I found that the default font for user interfaces like gimp or inkscape is "Bitstream Charter" which appeared in the Font manager example text also as hexadecimal boxes. I reinstalled the xfonts-base with no success. Then I disabled "Bitstream Charter" in the Font manager and installed it from download-free-fonts.com. It is not the final solution, because a system font should work from within the system, but at least i can use inkscape or gimp now with the default font.